# flow of magento view

Tags: magento-1.7

Actually I wanted to know the complete **flow** of a magento view. Suppose i am viewing the home page, can I ask how the flow of control goes through the PHTML, XML and PHP files , in order to view the home page? Basically wanted to know the **flow of control** of **magento**.
  If you  have a doubt in understanding my query , please let me know.

Regards

Comment: Turn on xdebug and have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to install this module: https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_Profiler/
It gives you a nice tree to explore the parts of the application executed.

It still will not expose everything, as for this a complete trace of the request would be better.

to explain everything is a bit hard, as magento has a lot of layers.
If you are more interested where to add your code, it needs if you look for the event/observer system of magento and where events get triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best bet to understand this is to use a debugger/xdebug. You can configure your IDE/editor to break on first line or set a break point in `index.php`. From there, start stepping into the code. Magento has many, many layers. I've found this approach has helped me personally more than any tutorial out there.

Answer (score 0):

Template hints with blocks are most always the first step when dissecting a magento page:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento

Your home page is generated by a CMS page, so the CMS->Pages in admin is going to be a good place to look for home page content.